# MySQL group by したデータに group by する前のデータ数を追加したい

Tags: mysql

[image: 画像(修正版)]

このような結果を取得したいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サブクエリを使えば良いのではないでしょうか。

```
select list.name, list.dinner, count(list.dinner) as count,
       (select count(name) from 食事リスト where name = list.name) as original
from 食事リスト as list
where list.name = '太郎' group by list.dinner;
```

Comment: なるほど！
select に直接サブクエリ使えたのですね。。。勉強不足でした

ありがとうございました！